# Add alias to values in query

Tags: php

Sorry if my question not so understandable.My English not so very good. I process all fields with quotes for SQL query and im doing this through function array_map() and I need to add to each field Alias of table
When im do it like that:

```
private function fieldClause($fields, $alias) 
{



    if(is_array($fields)) {

        $fields = array_map(function($field) {
            return" $alias.`$field`";
        },$fields);

    }

    $fields = implode(",", $fields);    
    return $fields;

}
```

Im getting error -  Undefined variable: alias

Comment: It's because `$alias` is outside the scope of the anonymous function. [php bind variable to function's scope in older PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532887/php-bind-variable-to-functions-scope-in-older-php) might answer your question.

Comment: thanks man all work!! )

Answer (score 0):

Inside your anonymous function the $alias variable is not defined, you have to add it as parameter to your function. Also take care with the backtick operator [1] even though I am not sure how the backtick is evaluated inside a double-quoted string.

This version will output "$field.$alias" per element inside your $fields array:

```
function mapAlias ($field, $alias) {
  return "$alias.$field";
}

if (is_array($fields)) {
  $fields= array_map("mapAlias", $fields, $alias);
}
```

[1] https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the anonymous function, you can use `use`.

```
private function fieldClause($fields, $alias) 
{
    if(is_array($fields)) {
        $fields = array_map(function($field) use ($alias) {
            return" $alias.`$field`";
        },$fields);
    }

    $fields = implode(",", $fields);    
    return $fields;

}
```

Otherwise create another function to use with `array_map()` and pass 2 arguments.